# How to do Simple Operation with IZPack

Tags: java, izpack

I use izpack-maven-plugin for my installation. Since we changed a lots of thing in our new version I wish to add those simple task.

-Copy File (Not from the stagging directory to the install directory but from the install directory to a backup folder for the customer)
-Delete File (Deleting file that are no longer needed in the install directory to keep the installation of the customer clean)

I searched and tried a couple thing, nothing seem to work. Look like i can't do those operation "out of the box" in the install.xml
So i tried to use the processPanel to execute either a .sh (Unix) or .bat(Windows) to do those task. Unfortunately when IzPack copy those file they don't have  the executable permission, so the installation crash with a "Permission Denied" error.

I'm running out of idea to fix my problem. Thanks a lots for your time

Comment: Have you tried adding a `<run-privileged/>` to the `<info>` section of your install.xml? It should make the installer attempt to run itself with elevated permissions.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? The only reference to this in my install.xml is <res id="ProcessPanel.Spec.xml" src="install/processPanelSpec.xml" /> where i call the file to be executed, Where do i put the <info> section? I do not have it specified and it is not on the codehausIzPack tutorial Thank a lots

Comment: Here's a link to [the docs](http://izpack.org/documentation/installation-files.html#the-information-element-info). `<info>` is supposed to be a child of `<installation>`

Comment: Ok, will try this asap. Will keep you updated. Thank again

Comment: Hi Tom, i got this <run-privileged condition="izpack.windowsinstall.vista|izpack.windowsinstall.7|izpack.linuxinstall" /> Unfortunately, well it work for launch of the jar. It prompt me for password. But in the process panel i still have my permission denied error when the .sh script try to be executed. I'd really like to fix this but as a work around my script can call the installation jar instead of the inverse but i don't really like this option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the executable tag in your pack definition to mark files as executable:

```
<packs>
  <pack ...>
    <executable targetfile="$INSTALL_PATH/bin/startup.sh"
      keep="true" stage="never" />
    ...
```

See the izpack documentation in chapter `The Packs Element <packs>` under section `<executable> - mark file executable or execute it.`

Comment: This would be a solution for my "work around" solution. Unfortunately i can't do that because i realized that i have to install THEN running the script (the script must be installed to be invoked). But in my current situation i need to run the script **before** installing the packs. My current solution (as a work around) is that the script invoke the executable .jar made by IZpack. Is there a way to do those basic task without the use of a script? (Using IzPack, I plan to use something else in the future) Thanks a lots for your help. (I will keep that solution in mind)

Comment: @drgn resurrecting this from the dead, but did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same question.

Comment: @TejasPendse Its been quite a while. What I would do is packaging the result of IzPack into a bash script as a payload. Which would result in a huge bash script self excutable that would run the pre-tasks then extracting the payload within the script and executing it to leave it as a 1 file installer. Have not worked with IzPack since 2012 Maybe there are better option in 2024! Wish you all the best

Comment: @drgn thank you for replying to a 12 year old question! As far as I can see this is the only way to do this.